# Symfony2 Access Denied Exception - More Details?

Tags: security, symfony, acl, roles, blacklist

I have the following problem:
In my symfony 2 application I have a voter called "ClientIpVoter", that checks if the client ip is blacklisted (http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/voters.html). If the ip is blacklisted, the Security Component throws a AccessDeniedException.

Other parts of the Security Component also throw a AccessDeniedException, for example if the user does not have the right roles.

Now my problem is, that I want to know why the AccessDeniedException was thrown, in order to do different stuff. For example displaying a message, or (if the AccessDeniedException was thrown because of insufficient roles), redirect the user to a page where he can for example confirm his account or email.

But the AccessDeniedException does not contain any information about the origin of the authorization problem. How would you implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the AccessDeniedException thrown for blacklisted IPs, wrap it in your own custom exception that adds extra info eg AccessDeniedBecauseOfInsufficientRolesException, then throw that exception again.
Pseudocode:

```
try
{
  BlacklistedVoterStuff();
}
catch( AccessDeniedException e )
{
  throw AccessDeniedBecauseOfInsufficientRolesException( e.message );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the BlacklistedVoterStuff is executed in a own context, where I only provide the implementation for the voter, which is then hooked in the authorization progress by symfony. And if my voter returns no access, the security component throws the AccessDeniedException with no detailled information about what happened.

Comment: Maybe you can get away with having your voter throw an exception instead of returning no access - it might bubble up into your context again?